# Angular2 / Ionic2 / TypeScript "two way" binding not updated if i use as reference in async function

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, observable, ionic2

I created a simple class in TypeScript:

```
export class LoginInformation {

    private _UserName: string;

    public get userName(): string {
        return this._UserName
    }

    public set userName(v: string) {
        this._UserName = v;
    }
}
```

Then i can instantiate the class:

```
private _LoginInformation: LoginInformation;
this._LoginInformation = new LoginInformation();
```

(and also implement the getter and setter), then assign a value

```
this.loginInformation.userName = "User1";
```

Now I can use the Object in my HTML:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="loginInformation.userName"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Now i can change my Object-Property

```
this.loginInformation.userName = "User2";
```

and the screen is updated in the expected way. Even if i set:

```
var self: LoginInformation = this.loginInformation;
self.userName = "User3";
```

everything is OK. But if I use an async function (e.g. get a value from the app preferences - plugin)

```
this._AppPreferences.fetch(
    (value) => {
        self.userName = "User4";
    },
    (error) => {
        alert("Error loading Configuration: " + error);
    },
    "LoginInformation");
```

the on-screen value is not updated. I thought that the assignment of the reference

```
self: LoginInformation = this.loginInformation
```

Should work in the expected way. But it seems that something is missing.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you try to give the same reference again, thats why it is not changing... try to clone/copy the loginInformtaion.

Comment: `this._LoginInformation` or `this.loginInformation`, which is it?  How does `fetch()` work?  Is it called inside the Angular zone? If not, try adding `ApplicationRef.tick()`, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ApplicationRef-class.html, to force change detection to run.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `self.userName`,  you should be able to use `this.userName` since you are in an arrow function:

```
this._AppPreferences.fetch(
    (value) => {
        this.userName = "User4";
    },
    (error) => {
        alert("Error loading Configuration: " + error);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't instantiate the service by yourself. You might end up having several instances instead of a singleton. Use NG2's dependency injection to do that automagically for you!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class LoginInformation {

    private _UserName: string;

    public get userName(): string {
        return this._UserName
    }

    public set userName(v: string) {
        this._UserName = v;
    }
}



import { Component }from '@angular/core';
import { LoginInformation } from './loginInformation.service';

@Component()
export class YourApp {
   constructor(_loginInformation: LoginInformation){

   }

}
```